# How to store tax in the database when tax consists of multiple taxes

Tags: mysql, database-design

We need to design Tax table for Billing System. Lets say we have a SGST (State Tax) and CGST(Central Tax) and

Final Intra-State Tax = SGST + CGST

**Tax table**

```
id
name
rate
```

**Tax table**

```
id  |   name      |    rate      |
1   |   SGST      |       5      |
2   |   CGST      |       5      |
```

How to store Intra-State Tax in the same table?

Should I add a field called 'taxIds' which will store a JSON array of other tax Ids like ?

```
 id  |   name      |    rate      |   taxIds
 1   |   SGST      |       5      | 
 2   |   CGST      |       5      |
 3   |   Intra     |              |  { taxIds : [1, 2] }
```

Is this a good idea?

Each Product will have tax Id.

Queries mainly include: `Calculate Monthly/Yearly Income`

Comment: The simple solution is to store each tax as a line item that links back up to a product and you can calculate the total as needed when you need to display the total taxes while still being able to get back to the individual amounts easily

Answer (score 2):

One (product) to many (taxes) are best done in a separate table (productid, taxid).

Putting multiple values in a single mysql column, especially one that is joined and searched on, will generally be hard to write and perform poorly.

Comment: but together they are one tax and I need to show in UI as a single tax as well

Comment: `SELECT product.id,SUM(tax.rate) * product.cost FROM product JOIN prod_tax on product.id = prod_tax.product_id JOIN tax ON prod_tax.tax_id = tax.id GROUP BY product.id`. As I said, write up the queries and see what they look like.

Comment: should be `(1 + SUM(tax.rate)) * product.cost` but you get the idea.

Comment: thank you for the query. But how do I still show that Intra-State Tax = SGST + CGST 
I need some way to just store in DB that Intra-State Tax is made up of SGST + CSGT

Comment: this does not help because I still need to represent Intra-State Tax = SGST + CGST in my datbase

Comment: Is it really going to change? Are there non Intra-State Taxes? Can you just define tax-ids < 10 as Intra-State (which would be an easier sort of solution)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95048/discussion-between-j10-and-danblack).

Answer (score 0):

How about Tax Groups?

Create two tables as follows

**TaxGroup**

```
GroupId(PK) |  Name
1           |  GST
```

**Tax**

```
TaxId(PK) | Name  | Rate  |GroupId (FK)
  1       | CGST  |  5    |   1
  2       | SGST  |  5    |   1
```

Then link the GroupId with your product table.