# How to store tax for a Product when tax rate for a Product can change and tax-exempted Products

Tags: mysql, database-design

**Product**

```
id
name
price
```

**Tax**

```
id
name
rate
```

**Product_Tax**

```
Product.id
Tax.id
effective date
expiry date
```

Is this a good design?

How to store Products that are tax-exempted?

Also, how to handle the case when the value of Tax changes for example VAT rate changes from 20% to 30% --> Should I store the value of rate in the Product_Tax table in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put tax exempt entries in the `Product_Tax` table.

Design is good ([already endorced](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/240679/how-to-store-tax-in-the-database-when-tax-consists-of-multiple-taxes/240681?noredirect=1#comment474647_240681) by me).

Comment: may be I should use a flag in the Product table for tax_exempt?

Comment: why bother? What does it gain? How would you use it? Do the query, it will hint if its a good idea.

Comment: With no entries for tax exempt products, you'll need to `LEFT JOIN` against `Product_Tax` rather than `JOIN` and keep in mind that the resulting entries will be `NULL` on the `Product_Tax` side of the join. That may have some effect on the result of some aggregate functions. e.g. Look at the `IFNULL` in [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8ff99784056199f04433207cc6c4c67e) as `SUM({all null values}) `is `NULL`

Comment: Thank you @danblack. Will take care of the NULL case.

Comment: Let's say the tax name is "VAT" and the current rate is 20% and now the value of this VAT changes to 30 %  after one year.
So, in that case, I should not allow changing the value of rate once it has been defined right so that the earlier invoices are not affected? 
Admin should add a new value "VAT30" and update the value for all Products?